# Unable to download deployment content from private github repository URI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I created new GitHub private repository, in that I added ARM templates for Azure key vault. After that I am trying to deploy ARM template from my local machine using PowerShell tool.

This is PowerShell script I used for deploying ARM template into azure.

```
#Login-AzureRmAccount

#region Parameters
$resourceGroupName='KZEU-ARMTMP-SB-DEV-RGP-01'
$location='eastus'
$parametersUri='E:\Kishore\Kishore GitHub\ARMTemplates\Parameters\StorageAccount.parameters.json'
$templateUri='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxxxxx/ARMTemplates/master/Templates/StorageAccount.json?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
$clientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="
#endregion

#region Login into Azure
 $SecurePassword = $key | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
 $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
 -argumentlist $clientID, $SecurePassword

 Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -Tenant "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -  ServicePrincipal

 Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 #endregion

 #region Check or Create Resource Group
 Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -ev notPresent -ea 0
 if($notPresent){ 
 Write-Host "Failover RG '$resourceGroupName' doesn't exist. Creating a new in $location...." -ForegroundColor Yellow
 New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $location
 }else{
Write-Host "Using existing resource group '$resourceGroupName'" -ForegroundColor Yellow;
 }

#endregion

#region Validate & Deploy ARM Templates
try{
  $templateValidationResult= Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile $templateUri -TemplateParameterFile $parametersUri -Verbose
if($templateValidationResult[0].Code-eq"InvalidTemplateDeployment"){
    Write-Host "Failed to validate ARM template"
    exit 1
}else{
    Write-Host "Successfully completed to validate ARM template"
    $deploymentResult= New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name StorageAccount-Deployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile $templateUri -TemplateParameterFile $parametersUri -Verbose
    if($deploymentResult.ProvisioningState-eq"Succeeded"){
        Write-Host "Successfully completed to deploy ARM template"
    }else{              
        Write-Host "Failed to deploy ARM template"
        exit 1
    }       
}
 }
 catch{
  $ex = $_.Exception | Format-List -Force
  Write-Host $ex
  }

 #endregion
```

When I run the above PowerShell script, then I am getting the error like

> Unable to download deployment content from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxx/demo-in/master/xxxx/keyVault.json"

[image: Unable to download template]

So, can anyone suggest me how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Can you add the script that you are running?

Comment: @KenWMSFT, Just now I updated my question.

Comment: you can write a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you can't deploy from a private repo ([see doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy#deploy-a-template-from-an-external-source)).  What you are trying to do is pass a template URI for Azure to read and it doesn't have permission to read from your private repo.  You have a couple options:

1. Do like the docs say and save the deploy.json to [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-powershell-sas-token)
   and protect it with a SAS token.
2. You can clone your repo locally and
   deploy from the local file.

Comment: Thanks @Ken, I know the above two processes you mentioned. But my client requirement is like to deploy ARM template from private GitHub repository by passing local parameter file to that ARM template.